# Wireless Network not discovered in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: wireless, 15.10

I am using Ubuntu 15.10, and it doesn't seem to discover my wireless network so I cannot connect.

How can I connect to wireless?

Please, any assistance would be appreciated,

Thanks

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   logical name: enp8s0
   version: c0
   serial: e8:9a:8f:da:af:d8
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.1-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:29 memory:da400000-da43ffff ioport:3000(size=128)

*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 1
   logical name: enx0c5b8f279a64
   serial: 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=cdc_ether driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=CDC Ethernet Device ip=192.168.8.100 link=yes multicast=yes


00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
09:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Can you add output of just `lspci`? And is your wireless adapter internal or is it a USB dongle? Please give more details on what your hardware is.

Comment: I do not see any wireless adapter there. Is it a built-in adapter? If this is the case, then the adapter is disabled in bios or broken. i do not see it.

Comment: i just added more information. are you saying there is no wireless card on the laptop?

Comment: There is no working wireless adapter, or it is turned off in bios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the wireless adapter is faulty, hence couldn't detect wireless network . Thanks @Pilot6